# Understanding Ext.extend and why calling superclass as a function without new

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having a difficult time understanding the implementation of Ext.extend function

It supports two syntax

`Ext.extend(extendedClass, baseClass, overrides);`

`extendedClass = Ext.extend(baseClass, overrides);`

So it normalizes the arguments like so

```
    var oc = Object.prototype.constructor;
    function(sb, sp, overrides){
        if(Ext.isObject(sp)){
            overrides = sp;
            sp = sb;
            sb = overrides.constructor != oc ? 
            overrides.constructor : 
            function(){sp.apply(this, arguments);};
```

What I don't understand is how `sb` is created if it is not passed in.

It checks if `overrides` is a config {}

```
>>> overrides = {a:1,b:2}
Object { a=1,b=2}
>>> overrides.constructor === Object.prototype.constructor
true
```

If it is not, then extendedClass is set to `overrides.constructor`

Otherwise, extendedClass is `function(){sp.apply(this, arguments)`

I read the difference between calling a constructor with or without `new`

http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/constructors-without-using-new.html

But what does that mean by calling the baseClass as a function without the `new` keyboard inside `function() { ... }` while passing the entire `arguments` to extend to the baseClass?

Thanks

The whole function looks like this

```
Ext.extend = function(){
    // inline overrides
    var io = function(o){
        for(var m in o){
            this[m] = o[m];
        }
    };
    var oc = Object.prototype.constructor;

    return function(sb, sp, overrides){
        if(Ext.isObject(sp)){
            overrides = sp;
            sp = sb;
            sb = overrides.constructor != oc ? 
            overrides.constructor : 
            function(){sp.apply(this, arguments);};
        }
        var F = function(){},
            sbp,
            spp = sp.prototype;

        F.prototype = spp;
        sbp = sb.prototype = new F();
        sbp.constructor=sb;
        sb.superclass=spp;
        if(spp.constructor == oc){
            spp.constructor=sp;
        }
        sb.override = function(o){
            Ext.override(sb, o);
        };
        sbp.superclass = sbp.supr = (function(){
            return spp;
        });
        sbp.override = io;
        Ext.override(sb, overrides);
        sb.extend = function(o){return Ext.extend(sb, o);};
        return sb;
    };
}();
```

Comment: Strange, as far as I can see, it doesn't matter if you passed in "sb" or not. It is always return. See the "return sb" around the bottom?
So, if you passed a variable in, you get a reference to sb. And if you did not you get the "returned" reference to sb.

Comment: And for "what does that mean by calling the baseClass as a function without the new keyword" : Actually there is a new keyword, if you look closely you'll see "new F()", where "F" has the prototype of "spp", where, again, has the prototype of "sp" (which is superclass). In short, "F" has the prototype of superclass. You'll also see "sb.prototype = new F()". --So "sb" is a [new] superclass object--

Comment: I'm not actually an expert in this myself. If it is still unclear, please tell. I'll try to explain in full with referenced information.